# Setup VisualPHPUnit with Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm using [VisualPHPUnit](https://github.com/VisualPHPUnit/VisualPHPUnit) as a GUI for my unit tests and I want to add it to my Laravel project.

I read [this guide](https://github.com/VisualPHPUnit/VisualPHPUnit/wiki/Laravel-setup) but it's obsolete being from 2015. There's no `bootstrap.php` file in `config` directory and there are no `test_directories` and `bootstraps` variables (I ran `grep -rn . -e test_directories` is Laravel directory).

Any idea what I can do to be able to add tests with `artisan` so they are working in VPU? Because Laravel test needs to extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` and VPU test needs to extend `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` and I can't get it running. Either I don't see the test in VPU when I use Laravel's extend or I can't use Laravel's functions like `visit` when I use VPU's extend.

Edit:
Here's my `PermissionTest.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Visualphpunit\Test;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class PermissionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/laravel/public';

    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/')->see('Logowanie');
    }

    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

...for which I get this error: `Fatal error: Class 'Visualphpunit\Test\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase not found in .../laravel/VisualPHPUnit-master/tests/PermissionTest.php on line 10`

Comment: Laravel's `TestCase` already extends `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

Comment: Well, I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Visualphpunit\Test\PermissionTest::visit() in .../laravel/VisualPHPUnit-master/tests/PermissionTest.php on line 20`. If VPU's TestCase extended Laravel's TestCase I would be able to use `visit` I guess.